# Better approach for getting the old values for the domain's collection associations properties

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Inside my domain class SupplierGroup , I have hasMany association .In my domain class for example : suppliers

### Code snipp of my domain class:

```
int id
String supplierGroupName
Long orgId
Date dateCreated
static hasMany =  [suppliers:OrganisationUnit] ..
```

I want to capture the old and new values of each modified property name .
But always get the current value of the suppliers property name  .And which is what I dont want.

```
def beforeUpdate(){
    println "BEFORE UPDATE: " + this.getPersistentValue('suppliers');
}

def afterUpdate(){
    println "AFTER UPDATE: " + this.suppliers;
}
```

### Console o\p :

BEFORE UPDATE: [com.xms.core.organisation.OrganisationUnit(13, ABC), com.xms.core.organisation.OrganisationUnit(14,DEF)]

AFTER UPDATE: [com.xms.core.organisation.OrganisationUnit(13, ABC), com.xms.core.organisation.OrganisationUnit(14,DEF)]

What is the best approach in Grails to collect all old and the new values of the association prop name ,mainly suppliers here in question? My current approach in controller layer is the following:

```
def multiOldIds = ""
def multiNewIds = ""
Block 1 :
supplierGroupInstance.suppliers.each(){ supplier ->
    if(multiOldIds != ""){
        multiOldIds += ","
    }
    //gets me the comma separated (ex: 1,2,3)
    multiOldIds += supplier.id
}
```

Block 2:

```
supplierGroupInstance.suppliers.each(){ supplier ->
    ifmultiNewIds != ""){
        multiNewIds += ","
    }
    //gets me the comma separated (ex: 1,2,3)
    multiNewIds += supplier.id
}
```

Block 1 gets executed before supplierGroupInstance.save(flush:true) and Block 2 after save flush.

And then persist the old and new data to db ..

```
if(!(multiOriginalIds.equals(multiNewIds))){
    actionLogService.savePreviousAndCurrentData(domainClass,id,multiOriginalIds,multiOriginalIdsCurrent,"suppliers")
}
```

Hence sum it all ..
Is my approach better towards capturing the old and new values of the hasMany props ?? Or is there any other approach ..pls advice.

### Segment of controller code :

..........

```
    //Performs the Update method on the Domain
    def update(Long id, Long version) {
        if(domainDebug) println domainName+"update() :params passed ${params}"

        if(domainHasUpdatedByXmsLoginId){
            params.updatedByXmsLoginId = sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:"id")
        }

        def multiOldIds = ""
        def dirtyPropertyNames = ""
        def multiNewIds = ""
            def supplierGroupInstance = SupplierGroup.get(id)
        String domainClass = this.class.getSimpleName().minus("Controller")
        //set the hasmany porperty values
        supplierGroupInstance.suppliers.each(){ supplier ->
        if(multiOldIds != ""){
            multiOldIds += ","
        }
        //gets me the comma separated (ex: 1,2,3)
        multiOldIds += supplier.id
        }
            if (version != null) {
                if (supplierGroupInstance.version > version) {
                    supplierGroupInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                              [message(code: 'supplierGroup.label', default: 'SupplierGroup')] as Object[],
                              "Another user has updated this SupplierGroup while you were editing")
                    render(view: "edit", model: [supplierGroupInstance: supplierGroupInstance])
                    return
                }
            }

            supplierGroupInstance.properties = params
        //below section is to retrive old and new values for primitive type propertyname
        dirtyPropertyNames = supplierGroupInstance.getDirtyPropertyNames()
        if(dirtyPropertyNames != null && dirtyPropertyNames.size() >0 && id !=null){
            for (dirtyPropertyName in dirtyPropertyNames) {
                 def originalValue = supplierGroupInstance.getPersistentValue(dirtyPropertyName)
                 def currentValue = supplierGroupInstance."${dirtyPropertyName}"
    //               println "current value----> " +currentValue
    //           println "original value----->" + originalValue

                 if(!(originalValue.equals(currentValue))){
actionLogService.savePreviousAndCurrentData(domainClass,id,originalValue,currentValue,dirtyPropertyName)
                 }
            }
        }


            if (!supplierGroupInstance.save(flush: true)) {
                render(view: "edit", model: [supplierGroupInstance: supplierGroupInstance])
                return
            }

        supplierGroupInstance.suppliers.each(){ supplier ->
            if(multiNewIds != ""){
                multiNewIds += ","

            }
            multiNewIds += supplier.id

        }



            if(!(multiOldIds.equals(multiNewIds))){
         actionLogService.savePreviousAndCurrentData(domainClass,id,multiOriginalIds,multiOriginalIdsCurrent,"suppliers")
            }




            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'supplierGroup.label', default: 'SupplierGroup'), supplierGroupInstance.id])
        if(domainHasLastUpdated){
            redirect(action: "list", params: [sort:"lastUpdated", order:"desc"])
        } else {
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The

```
getPersistentValue
```

works well on domain's field which is pulling domain's original state from hibernate cache. Having said that, this will work if you do the

```
beforeUpdate()
```

in supplier/OrganizationUint end.

Comment: Thanks Aramiti for your answer. Tried using your approach but gets me the current values for the association property[supplier/OrganizationUnit].

Comment: The other option is to clone your object before update. This way the cloned object has a different memory location thus retains the old value.